# Using QT events in the destructor of QApplication - hanging

Tags: c++, qt

I'm working with a QT GUI application which is having problems processing events during the QApplicaton destructor.  A library I use (that I can't change) uses a QEventLoop.  It has written some data to a socket and seems to be waiting for a response.  The debugger shows that QEventDispatcherWin32::processEvents is looping and using up CPU.

I've managed to get it to work by deleting some particular widgets earlier on.  However, this seems a bit random!

We are logging off our server when a widget is destroyed.  Depending on what widgets are created, I sometimes get the hang and sometimes don't.

This is the exec call that hangs -

```
  m_timedout = false;
  QEventLoop loop;
  QTimer timer;
  timer.setSingleShot(true);
  connect(&timer, SIGNAL(timeout()), this, SLOT(slt_timeout()));
  connect(&timer, SIGNAL(timeout()), &loop, SLOT(quit()));
  timer.start(1800000);
  connect(this, SIGNAL(sig_response(int, int, QByteArray)), &timer, SLOT(stop()));
  connect(this, SIGNAL(sig_response(int, int, QByteArray)), &loop, SLOT(quit()));
  loop.exec(QEventLoop::ExcludeUserInputEvents);
```

So what am I asking?  I'm very new to QT and don't understand all the concepts but it sounds worrying to me that we are relying on QT event processing during the destructor of the application.  Is that a valid thing to do?  Won't QT have started to wind down?

Is there anything else that would cause that hang?

Comment: You could set `QGuiApplication::setQuitOnLastWindowClosed` to false to keep the application running, even after the widget was destroyed. Disconnect and only after that call `QGuiApplication::quit` to exit the application.

Comment: I had a play with that but then couldn't find how to make it do anything when the last window was closed.  It wouldn't call lastWindowClosed when I added it as a slot.  But anyway - I see now that our Application is deleted by a kind of controlling class and perhaps that's where I need to put our logoff code.  Thanks for the pointer!